# sed / awk - remove newline with condition

Tags: awk, sed, newline

I have the following text:

```
pane    0   1   :title  1   :*  1   :/home/user 0   app1name    :
app1 -some -stuff
pane    0   1   :title  1   :*  2   :/home/user 0   app2name    :
pane    0   1   :title  1   :*  3   :/home/user 1   app3name    :
app3
window  0   1   1   :*  somelongstuff
state   0
```

what i'm trying to achive is remove newline after ending `:` but only when following line doesnt start with `pane\t` or `window\t`

So the final output should look like this:

```
pane    0   1   :title  1   :*  1   :/home/user 0   app1name    :app1 -some -stuff
pane    0   1   :title  1   :*  2   :/home/user 0   app2name    :
pane    0   1   :title  1   :*  3   :/home/user 1   app3name    :app3
window  0   1   1   :*  somelongstuff
state   0
```

I tried several sed and awk, such as
`sed '/\npane\t/ n; /window\t/ n; N; s/:\n/:/g'` or `awk '{ORS=(/pane\t/?"":RS)}1'` but some way they all fail

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Post those efforts to the question

Comment: @Inian as requested i added a couple of (failed) attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf "%s%s", p, ((p ~ /:$/) && !/^(pane|window)\t/ ? "" : ORS)} {p=$0} END{print p}' file
pane    0       1       :title  1       :*      1       :/home/user     0       app1name        :app1   -some   -stuff
pane    0       1       :title  1       :*      2       :/home/user     0       app2name        :
pane    0       1       :title  1       :*      3       :/home/user     1       app3name        :app3
window  0       1       1       :*      somelongstuff
state   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 'print "\n" if $chomped && /^(pane|window)\t/; $chomped = /:$/ ? chomp : 0' -- file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, printing each line after processing
- [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) removes the trailing newline if present. It also returns the number of removed characters.
- `/:$/` matches if the colon is the last character on a line.
- `? :` is the ternary operator. If the condition is true, i.e. if the colon is the last character on a line, we remove the newline if it's present and set the `$chomped` variable to 1, otherwise it's set to 0.
- When reading a line, the `$chomped` variable tells us whether a newline was removed from the previous line. If it was but the current line starts with a `pane` or `window` followed by a `\t`, we insert the newline back.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is not really suitable for this task. You would have to fiddle with sed's hold space to make it work. At that point it's easier to switch to another tool.

Here's a `perl` script

```
perl -np0 -e 's/:\n(?!pane\t|window\t)/:/g'
```

Use it in a pipe or pass your file name as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/:\n/{/\n\(pane\|window\)/!s/\n//};P;D' file
```

Open a window of two lines throughout the length of the file. If the first line ends in `:` and the second line does not begin with `pane` or `window` remove the newline. Print/delete the first line and repeat.

Or, on reflection:

```
sed 'N;/:\n\(window\|pane\)/!s/:\n/:/;P;D' file
```

Comment: Since this sed command doesnt consider the `:` to possibly remove the `\n` i should take care of excluding also `state` (last line keyword). And maybe add `\t` after pane, window and state to better ensure it doesnt remove `\n` when it shouldnt. Came up with this: `sed 'N;/\n\(pane\t\|window\t\|state\t\)/!s/\n//;P;D' file`, which seems to work. Am i correct?